# Orion Context Broker functional test failure

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have successfully forked and built the Context Broker source code on a CentOS 6.9 VM and now I am trying to run the functional tests as the [official documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/build_source/index.html) suggests. First, I installed the `accumulator-server.py` script:

```
$ make install_scripts INSTALL_DIR=~
```

Verified that it is installed:

```
$ accumulator-server.py -u

Usage: accumulator-server.py --host <host> --port <port> --url <server url> --pretty-print -v -u

Parameters:
  --host <host>: host to use database to use (default is '0.0.0.0')
  --port <port>: port to use (default is 1028)
  --url <server url>: server URL to use (default is /accumulate)
  --pretty-print: pretty print mode
  --https: start in https
  --key: key file (only used if https is enabled)
  --cert: cert file (only used if https is enabled)
  -v: verbose mode
  -u: print this usage message
```

And then run the functional tests:

```
$ make functional_test INSTALL_DIR=~
```

But the test fails and exits with the message below:

```
024/927: 0000_ipv6_support/ipv4_ipv6_both.test ........................................................................  (FAIL 11 - SHELL-INIT exited with code 1) testHarness.sh/IPv6 IPv4 Both : (0000_ipv6_support/ipv4_ipv6_both.test) 
make: *** [functional_test] Error 11
$
```

I checked the file `../0000_ipv6_support/ipv4_ipv6_both.shellInit.stdout` for any hint on what may be going wrong but error log does not lead me anywhere:

```
{ "dropped" : "ftest", "ok" : 1 }
accumulator running as PID 6404
Unable to start listening application after waiting 30
```

Does anyone have any idea about what may be going wrong here?

Comment: Did you installed the accumulator script (typically using `make install_scripts`)? Is accumulator script working correctly? Please edit your question to add the output of the `accumulator-server.py -u` command. Thanks!

Comment: @fgalan Yes, I did and it seems to be working correctly. I edited the question to add the information you asked for.

Comment: In order to see if it is something related with IPv6, try to remove the `cases/0000_ipv6_support` directory (you can always re-create it from git) and run again `make ft`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @fgalan, I did as you say and now I get the same error for `0000_large_requests/notification_different_sizes.test`

Comment: By "the same error" you mean tha the `.shellInit.stdout` shows the same error about "Unable to start listening application after waiting 30"? Or the fail pattern is different in that case?

Comment: Yes, I see the same error (Unable to start listening...) in `notification_different_sizes.shellInit.stdout`

Comment: Skip also that case in the same way (i.e. removing the directory). Let's try to find the set of failing tests in your environment during a full pass.

Comment: @fgalan, after skipping more than 50 tests I decided to perform a deeper check and found the cause of the problem. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the script which prints the error line `Unable to start listening application after waiting 30` and noticed that stderr for `accumulator-server.py` is logged into the `/tmp` folder.

The `accumulator_9977_stderr` file had this log: `0000_ipv6_support/ipv4_ipv6_both.shellInit: line 27: accumulator-server.py: command not found`

Once I saw this log I understood the mistake I made. I was running the
 functional tests with sudo and the `secure_path` was being used instead of my `PATH` variable.

So at the end, running the functional tests with the command below solved the issue for me.

```
$ sudo "PATH=$PATH" make functional_test INSTALL_DIR=~
```

This can also be solved by editing the /etc/sudoers file by:

```
$ sudo visudo
```

and modifying the secure_path value.